# Creating a Scrollable Popover Without Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, popover

So I've been trying to create a scrollable popover while hiding the scrollbar, but it's only been working on Chrome thanks to the beautiful:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display:none;
}
```

I've created [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/1947/) to demonstrate.

I've tried many suggested solutions, including [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll), but it didn't work (you can see the CSS suggested commented out in my fiddle).

I'd really like to get this working in all major browsers (Chrome & Safari are covered, need FF/Opera/IE 9 and above).

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the cleanest solution, but **it works**.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/1948/

**Add a child div under the parent** (remember to add closing tag for it!)

```
<div class="parent"><div class="child"><ul><li>Fixed header</li></ul><ul class="scrollable"><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li><li>13</li><li>14</li><li>15</li><li>16</li><li>17</li><li>18</li><li>19</li><li>20</li><li>21</li><li>22</li><li>22</li><li>23</li><li>24</li><li>25</li><li>26</li><li>27</li><li>28</li></ul></div></div>
```

**CSS for parent and child**

```
.parent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
 height: 100%;
 width: 115%; /* Use width to push scrollbar out of sight due using overflow:hidden above */
 overflow: auto;
}
```

**Tested on**

- Internet Explorer 11 (Technical Preview)
- Google Chrome 44.0.2376.0 (canary)
- Firefox 38.0.5